Play call sound while connected
How to use the Linfone library to reproduce beeps while there is a connection (as happens when you call on a regular phone). In the core class, there are playLocal methods, ring, and ringback variables, but there is no effect when using them. Maybe someone has solved this problem and can provide an example?
func playRing() {
    guard let ringtonePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "longCall_wav", ofType: "wav")
    else {
        NSLog("Ringtone file not found")
        return
    }

    do {
        try mCore.playLocal(audiofile: ringtonePath)
        mCore.rin
    } catch {
        print("call state changed  \(NSLog(error.localizedDescription))")
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
